# arraylist returning only one record

Tags: android, sqlite

I tried to retrieve all data from database and put it into arraylist  but i get only one record of table. here is my code :

```
where Birthdates is arraylist.

public ArrayList<String> read()
{
Birthdates.clear();
String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM Birthday_Reminder";
Cursor crs=database.rawQuery(selectQuery,null);

System.out.println("In read");
if(crs.moveToFirst())
{
    do  {
        Toast.makeText(con,"adding to arraylist", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Birthdates.add(crs.getString(crs.getColumnIndex("B_Date")));
        }
    while (crs.moveToNext());

}
return Birthdates;

}
```

Comment: what is the number of Toast message count?  is it one?

Answer (score 0):

i am doing this way by using getters and setters

```
package com.sunil.smilee;

public class DataOfUser {

    int _id;
    String _data;
    String _date;

    // Empty constructor
    public DataOfUser(){

    }


    // constructor

    // getting ID
    public int getID(){
        return this._id;
    }

    // setting id
    public void setID(int id){
        this._id = id;
    }

    // getting name
    public String getD(){
        return this._data;
    }

    // setting name
    public void setD(String s){
        this._data = s;
    }
    //
    public void setDate(String string) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         this._date = string;
    }

   public String getDate(){
            return this._date ;
        }

}

  // Add it in database class or change accordingly
 // Getting All Contacts
        public List<DataOfUser> getAllContacts() {
            List<DataOfUser> dist = new ArrayList<DataOfUser>();
            // Select All Query
            String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + ITEM.TABLE_DATA;

            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

            // looping through all rows and adding to list
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    DataOfUser contact = new DataOfUser();
                    contact.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                    contact.setD(cursor.getString(1));
                    contact.setDate(cursor.getString(2));


                    dist.add(contact);//add data in list
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                  //
            }

            // return contact list
            return dist;
        }
```